# Introducing new variable in anonymous class override

Tags: java, variables, overriding, anonymous-class

I'm not facing any particular problem regarding anonymous class implementation, but I noticed something while toying around that strikes me as quite interesting. Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Foo {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    } // foo
} // Foo
```

and in a main class, I have the following:

```
public class Main {
    
    public final Foo foo;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo = new Foo() {
            
            public String test = "test";
            
            @Override
            public void foo() {
                super.foo();
                test = test + test;
                System.out.println(test);
            } // foo
        
        } // anonymous override

        // following line throws exception
        // System.out.println(foo.test);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            foo.foo();
        } // for   
    } // main
```

The following is what's printed out to the console:

```
foo
test

foo
testtest

foo
testtesttesttest
```

The `String test` cannot be accessed from outside of the anonymous override, no matter what I do. Even when I erase the line "test = test + test" and declare test as static and final, it is still inaccessible from outside of the anonymous implementation.

I have no particular need for using a variable in this kind of situation, but it makes me curious if there's something that I'm missing here. Just, WHAT IF I needed to embed a new variable into an override just like I did above in the example. Is there any way that I could possibly access the variable "test" from outside of the anonymous override without using an abstract method or variables in the "parent" class?

Comment: I see nothing unique about the fact that the class is anonymous here. You could do the same with an external, concrete implementation

Comment: Your code doesn't compile

Comment: I'd expect the output to be testtest, testtesttesttest, testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest, since you double up *before* printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one instance of anonymous extension of class `Foo` (the instance that `foo` points to). so it should not be surprising that changes to the one instance are cumulative.

The variable `foo` is a reference to a `Foo`, and a `Foo` does not have a `test` member, so there's nothing to reference.

You can't write a cast to the class that does have a`test` member, since it does not have a name you can utter.

You could probably get there with reflection.

This all seems exactly as expected with class hierarchies.
An anonymous subclass is just a subclass without a name that can appear in source code.

If you actually need access to `test` then declare a named subclass instead of an anonymous one. Suitable choice of access modifiers will allow you to declare `foo` suitably, e.g. as `FooBar foo` if the subclass is called FooBar.